# How to get the coordinate of the nodes of a circular tree by ggtree

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtree

I want to know how to get the node coordinates of the deformed ggtree. The coordinates obtained by `ggtree::fortify()` are valid in a square tree, but I don't know how to get coordinates for other tree points with shapes such as circular or slanted. I guess it's going to take some polar conversion.
Here is my code to make tree:

```
library(ggtree)
tr <- rtree(10)
ggtree::fortify(tr)
ggtree(tr,layout = "fan")->a
```

The fortified data is not consistent with the plane cartesian coordinates of the points on the graph.

```
# A tibble: 19 × 9
   parent  node branch.length label isTip     x     y branch angle
    <int> <int>         <dbl> <chr> <lgl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     11     1        0.614  t6    TRUE  0.614  1     0.307   36 
 2     13     2        0.659  t9    TRUE  1.83   2     1.50    72 
 3     14     3        0.647  t5    TRUE  2.21   3     1.89   108 
 4     15     4        0.0817 t2    TRUE  2.62   4     2.58   144 
 5     15     5        0.564  t1    TRUE  3.11   5     2.82   180 
 6     18     6        0.663  t4    TRUE  2.51   8     2.18   288 
 7     19     7        0.607  t10   TRUE  2.62   9     2.31   324 
 8     19     8        0.696  t8    TRUE  2.71  10     2.36   360 
 9     17     9        0.975  t3    TRUE  2.68   7     2.19   252 
10     16    10        0.683  t7    TRUE  1.66   6     1.32   216 
11     11    11        0      NA    FALSE 0      2.95  0      106.
12     11    12        0.807  NA    FALSE 0.807  4.91  0.403  177.
13     12    13        0.364  NA    FALSE 1.17   2.88  0.988  104.
14     13    14        0.397  NA    FALSE 1.57   3.75  1.37   135 
15     14    15        0.975  NA    FALSE 2.54   4.5   2.06   162 
16     12    16        0.175  NA    FALSE 0.981  6.94  0.894  250.
17     16    17        0.723  NA    FALSE 1.70   7.88  1.34   284.
18     17    18        0.144  NA    FALSE 1.85   8.75  1.78   315 
19     18    19        0.162  NA    FALSE 2.01   9.5   1.93   342
```

I tried to parse the ggplot object directly, using `ggplot2::ggplot_build()`
Here is my code:

```
ggplot2::ggplot_build(a)[["data"]][[2]]
```

The output is, take node t6 (node 1 , parent11) as example:

```
$data[[2]]
   node parent         x        y PANEL group      xend      yend colour linewidth linetype alpha
1     1     11 0.0000000 2.953125     1    -1 0.0000000  1.000000  black       0.5        1    NA
```

But t6 is definitely not anywhere near (0,2.95) or (0,1)
[plot a with tip label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1SBW.jpg)
The expected coorinate is more like the middle of the plot.
I really need help, please.